# listview with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i want to show a listview with check box like

```
          checkbox listitem1
          checkbox listitem2
          checkbox listitem3
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

If click on any listitem in listview then the corresponding check box checked will be true . I tried below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<CheckBox android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/list_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    ></CheckBox>
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/songname"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="10px"
 android:layout_marginLeft="60px"/>
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/artist"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="30px"
 android:layout_marginLeft="60px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The class file is

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
 list.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));

private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
       private LayoutInflater mInflater;

       public EfficientAdapter(Context context) 
       {
       mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       }

       public int getCount() 
       {
       return title.length;
       }

       public Object getItem(int position) 
       {
       return position;
       }

       public long getItemId(int position) 
       {
           return position;
       }

       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
       {
       ViewHolder holder;
       if (convertView == null) 
       {
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.selectsongs, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();

       holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songname);
       holder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
       holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox);    
       convertView.setTag(holder);
       } 
       else 
       {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       holder.title.setText(title[position]);  
       holder.artist.setText(artist[position]);

       return convertView;
       }

       static class ViewHolder 
       {
       TextView title,artist;

       CheckBox check;

       }
       }
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("name",title[position]);

}
```

but in this the OnClickItemClickListener on the listview is not working. The checkbox checkable is true when i click on the check box not on listitem in listview. So please tell me how to show the listview with checkbox and also listitem checkbox checkable is true when i click on the listitem.

Best Regards.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better to accomplish the list using a [ChechBoxPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html).

The main advantage of using preference is that you don't need to write code to save the value and you can easily get the value in any activity. The value is stored in the android preference as a key-pair value. You can refer the value using the 'KeyName'.

The following link will help you to get an idea about this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2010/12/03/android---creating-a-custom-preferences-activity-screen.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. i have just fixed it 2 days before:

In the : public View getView

```
 cb =(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
          cb.setChecked(etat[position]);

          final int xt=position;

          cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                if(arg0.isChecked())
                {           
                    etat[xt]=true;
                    //Update the state of Checkbox to the: "tabEtat"
                    Etat.getInstance().setAddIdEtat(String.valueOf(xt));
                        }                         
                }
                else
                {
                    //Update the state of Checkbox to the : "tabEtat"
                    Etat.getInstance().setDeleteIdEtat(String.valueOf(xt));
                        }                          
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

After two hours effort ,i got solution for it.

```
/**
*This is Adapter class 
*/
  public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private String[] stringArray;
        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater inflator;
        int checkbox;
        /**
         * 
         * @param context
         * @param stringArray
         */
        public CustomListAdapter(Context  context, String[] stringArray) 
        {
            this.mContext=context;
            this.stringArray=stringArray;
            this.inflator= (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return stringArray.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            final MainListHolder mHolder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                mHolder = new MainListHolder();
                v = inflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, null);
                mHolder.txt=(CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                v.setTag(mHolder);
            } 
            else
            {
                mHolder = (MainListHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            mHolder.txt.setText(stringArray[position]);
            mHolder.txt.setTextSize(12);
            mHolder.txt.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

        /**
         * When checkbox image is set By setImageFromResourceCheckBox(int id) method...Otherwise it takes default
         */
            if(checkbox!=0)
                mHolder.txt.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.android_button);

            mHolder.txt.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            return v;
        }
        class MainListHolder 
        {
            private CheckedTextView txt;

        }
        /***
         * Setting Image for Checkbox
         * @param id
         * 
         */
        public void setImageFromResourceCheckBox(int id)
        {
            this.checkbox=id;
        }


    }
```

And Activity class should be like this.

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener  {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        CustomListAdapter c=new CustomListAdapter(this,GENRES);
      //  c.setImageForCheckBox(R.drawable.android_button);//Image for checkbox
        setListAdapter(c);

        final ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
      //  listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);// For single mOde

        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setItemChecked(2, true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    private static  String[] GENRES = new String[] {
        "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
        "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"
    };
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {

    SparseBooleanArray sp=getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

    String str="";
    for(int i=0;i<sp.size();i++)
    {
        str+=GENRES[sp.keyAt(i)]+",";
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```