# when i click an item than item image alone should appear and unselected listitem's image should disappear

Tags: android, listview

In my activity intially Position 0 item alone get checkmarked ,when i click it disappears.same way all items.but what i want is.only one item image should appaer if i click other item previous item image should disappear.

In getview() intially i took position 0 item as checkmarked.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int position, long id) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
                  if (position ==0)
                  {
                      itemToggled[position] = ! itemToggled[position];
                      imageView.setImageResource(itemToggled[position] ?  R.drawable.empty :R.drawable.checked);

              }else{
                       itemToggled[position] = ! itemToggled[position];
                 imageView.setImageResource(itemToggled[position] ? R.drawable.checked : R.drawable.empty);

              }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need some data structure to keep track of checked items. you can use boolean array in your custom adapter.

the same question here [Problem with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143201/problem-with-checkbox/7143252#7143252)

and also you can find some usefull links in the answer.