# how to add checkbox in listview in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, android-checkbox

I used `ListView` in my `Activity`. Following my code-snippet:

```
public class Home1 extends ListActivity {

    private static final int ADD_MENU_ITEM = 1;
    // private static final String TAG_COMPANY = "company";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://api-11hr.anovatesoft.com/v1/list";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER = "contactnumber";
    private static final String TAG_POSTAL_CODE = "postalcode";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
    SessionManager session;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String apikey;

    GPSTracker gps;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
    private String status;
    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
    private int c =1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();


        // apikey
        apikey = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_api);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
      /* swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        while (c != 1) {
            onRefresh();
        }*/

        ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home1.this, Selected.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        ImageView profile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile);
        profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Home1.this, Setting.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        Gps_func();


        final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();

        //Set name and email in global/application context
        apikey = globalVariable.getApikey();
        status = globalVariable.getStatus();


        latitude = globalVariable.getLatitude();
        longitude = globalVariable.getLongitude();
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();
        //   lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        //   lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                //  contactList.add(.get(position).toString());
                String company = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.company)).getText().toString();

                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();
                String address = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString();
                String operating_hours = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.operating_hours)).getText().toString();

                String contact = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact)).getText().toString();
                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Adds.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, company);
                in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, description);
                in.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                in.putExtra(TAG_POSTAL_CODE, operating_hours);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER, contact);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }


    private void Gps_func() {

        gps = new GPSTracker(Home1.this);

        // check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // \n is for new line
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("tag", "Longitude:\n" + longitude + "\n Latitude: \n" + latitude);

        } else {

            gps.showSettingsAlert();

            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();


                Log.d("tag", "Longitude:\n" + longitude + "\n Latitude: \n" + latitude);

            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Gps_func();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();

            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(10);
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home1.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler1 sh = new ServiceHandler1(apikey, latitude, longitude);


            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler1.POST);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String contact_number = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER);
                        String postalcode = c.getString(TAG_POSTAL_CODE);


                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        // contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                        contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contact.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        contact.put(TAG_POSTAL_CODE, postalcode);
                        contact.put(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER, contact_number);

                        contactList.add(contact);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, company);
             in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, description);
             in.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
             in.putExtra(TAG_POSTAL_CODE, operating_hours);
             in.putExtra(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER, contact);
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Home1.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item1, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_USERNAME, TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_POSTAL_CODE, TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER,
            }, new int[]{
                    R.id.company, R.id.description, R.id.address, R.id.operating_hours, R.id.contact});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

   /* @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                contactList.clear();
                new GetContacts().execute();
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }*/
```

I want to add `CheckBox` in my ListView and show the selected items by CheckBox in another Activity. But I don't know how to do it. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [listview with checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376082/listview-with-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code similar to your case

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checklist);
    db = new DatabaseHandlerChecklist(this);
    initList();

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addChecklist);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    ChecklistActivity.this);
            add.setTitle("Add checklist");
            add.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon);
            add.setMessage("Enter text : ");
            final EditText content = new EditText(ChecklistActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            content.setLayoutParams(lp);
            add.setView(content);

            add.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String SContent =  content.getText().toString();
                    if (SContent.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(ChecklistActivity.this, "Insert text first !", 2000).show();
                    } else {
                        Checklist check = new Checklist(SContent, 0);
                        db.insert(check);
                        adapter.add(check);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        initList();
                        Toast.makeText(ChecklistActivity.this, "Text added !", 2000).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            add.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            add.show();
        }
    });

    delete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.deleteChecklist);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db.delete();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            initList();
            Toast.makeText(ChecklistActivity.this, "Deleted !", 2000).show();
        }
    });
}

public void initList() {
    list = db.getAll();
    adapter = new ChecklistAdapter(this, R.layout.content_checklist, list);
    ListView checklist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    checklist.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ChecklistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Checklist> {

    Context context;
    List<Checklist> checklist = new ArrayList<Checklist>();
    int layoutResourceId;

    public ChecklistAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            List<Checklist> objects) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.checklist = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckBox chk = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_checklist,
                    parent, false);
            chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(chk);

            chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Checklist changeChecklist = (Checklist) cb.getTag();
                    changeChecklist.setStatus(cb.isChecked() == true ? 1 : 0);
                    db.update(changeChecklist);
                }
            });
        } else {
            chk = (CheckBox) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Checklist current = checklist.get(position);
        chk.setText(current.getContent());
        chk.setChecked(current.getStatus() == 1 ? true : false);
        chk.setTag(current);
        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater floatMenu = getMenuInflater();
    floatMenu.inflate(R.menu.float_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about :
        Intent change = new Intent("com.interactive.writeit.ABOUT");
        startActivity(change);
        break;
    case R.id.help :
        Intent change1 = new Intent("com.interactive.writeit.HELP");
        startActivity(change1);
        break;
    case R.id.exit : 
        AlertDialog.Builder exit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        exit.setTitle("Exit");
        exit.setMessage("Are you sure want to exit ?");
        exit.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        exit.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        exit.show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

You must create Checklist object which hold your ListView content which contain Checkbox and TextView.